# How to map jgrapht Graph<Foo,E> to another Graph<Bar,E>?

Tags: java, data-conversion, jgrapht

I have the following graph:

```
    private final Graph<Foo, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = buildGraph();

@Override
public Graph<Foo, DefaultWeightedEdge> buildGraph() {
    return GraphTypeBuilder
            .directed()
            .allowingSelfLoops(false)
            .weighted(true)
            .allowingMultipleEdges(false)
            .vertexClass(Foo.class)
            .edgeClass(DefaultWeightedEdge.class)
            .buildGraph();
}
```

How can I Map this to a Graph with Type `Graph<Bar, DefaultWeightedEdge>` ?

---

I added to Nikolais answer mapping the edge aswell, since it was not converting the source and target types of the DefaultWeightedEdge:

```
  public <V, Vv> Graph<Vv, DefaultWeightedEdge> convert(Graph<V, DefaultWeightedEdge> source, Function<V, Vv> vertexMapper) {
Graph<Vv, DefaultWeightedEdge> result = GraphTypeBuilder.<Vv, DefaultWeightedEdge>forGraphType(source.getType()).edgeClass(DefaultWeightedEdge.class).buildGraph();
source.vertexSet().forEach(v -> result.addVertex(vertexMapper.apply(v)));
source
    .edgeSet()
    .forEach(
        e -> {
          V sourceV = source.getEdgeSource(e);
          Vv mappedSourceV = vertexMapper.apply(sourceV);
          V targetV = source.getEdgeTarget(e);
          Vv mappedTargetV = vertexMapper.apply(targetV);
          result.addVertex(mappedSourceV);
          result.addVertex(mappedTargetV);
          DefaultWeightedEdge ee = result.addEdge(mappedSourceV, mappedTargetV);
          double edgeWeight = source.getEdgeWeight(e);
          result.setEdgeWeight(ee, edgeWeight);
        });
return result;
```

}

Could we do this more elegant in a functional / more generic way by adding an edge mapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually rather straight forward after having a look at `clone()` in [AbstractBaseGraph](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/graph/AbstractBaseGraph.java). I have put the complete code with a small demo in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/curiosag/434e121a95dc38510c35a3f5cfa2743f).

```
public static <V, Vv, E> Graph<Vv, E> convert(Graph<V, E> source, Function<V, Vv> vertexMapper) {
    Graph<Vv, E> result = GraphTypeBuilder.<Vv, E>forGraphType(source.getType()).buildGraph();

    source.vertexSet().forEach(v -> result.addVertex(vertexMapper.apply(v)));
    for (E e : source.edgeSet()) {
        Vv s = vertexMapper.apply(source.getEdgeSource(e));
        Vv t = vertexMapper.apply(source.getEdgeTarget(e));
        result.addVertex(s);
        result.addVertex(t);
        result.addEdge(s, t, e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you review my latest edit please?